# Apache lucene update stored field

Tags: apache, lucene, indexing, field

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why Lucene doesn't support any type of update to an existing document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12185406/why-lucene-doesnt-support-any-type-of-update-to-an-existing-document)

Is it possible to update stored field value after document was indexed(without reindexing it)?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: No.

You need to delete and re-add the document, it's stored fields and it's indexed fields.
See [IndexWriter.updateDocument() Javadoc](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html):

> "Updates a document by first deleting the document(s) containing term and then adding the new document. The delete and then add are atomic as seen by a reader on the same index (flush may happen only after the add)."

One more alternative could be to store any data that needs updating outside of Lucene (say in a relational DB).

There's all sorts of [work in progress](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-dev/201207.mbox/%3C646949197.107669.1343332355563.JavaMail.jiratomcat@issues-vm%3E) to allow in place updates, to stored or index fields, however nothing concrete for Lucene V4 or earlier.